# How to replace basement floor that has begun to rot?

Tags: repair, flooring, subfloor, water-damage, basement-refinishing

The home I am moving into has a basement that seems to have a rotting wood subfloor. (Not sure if this is the correct term). There is a concrete base, and some inches above, what I suspect to be wood. The area is carpeted, but walking across it, you can feel it sink and it feels like broken wood underneath. Is this something I would be able to repair fairly easily on my own, or should I leave it to a professional? Thank you for any advice, I don't know where to start.

Comment: Start by taking up the carpet so you can see what you are really dealing with.

Comment: I agree that removal of the carpet will be the first step, wood decking above concrete is one way to have a dry floor, as a new home owner this is a good place to start learning, why would I say this? It’s non structural.  Once you expose the “bad area” post a photo with a new question and there are many that can help with patching concrete, repairing decking and even putting down carpet.

Comment: You're going to want to determine WHY the existing floor is having problems.  It could be as simple as "it was poorly built to begin with" but there may be moisture issues that are causing the wood to deteriorate and/or rot.  If you don't identify and correct the root cause, it will just happen again.

Comment: Post some pictures here.  What do you mean by "some inches above"?  What is between the wood and the concrete?  My suggestion: Wait a year and watch the basement during different seasons and especially after rain storms.  See how much water comes in and where.  If the carpet and floor beneath it has obviously ever been wet or begun to rot, tear it all out immediately but then wait and watch.  If it's only rotten on one side or one corner you may be able to make adjustments and repairs.  Wait and watch.

Comment: Removing and replacing the wood, you can easy do yourself.  This is simple work.  Leaks/moisture problems and laying down carpet, maybe have professional do.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you want to do it yourself or not.

If so, rent a dumpster/skip "for construction debris" and start with removing the rotten mess, which needs to be done either way, and will save you some money if you end up deciding to hire a professional after doing that.

Then solve the water problems (rot does not happen without them.)

Then sort out how you want to proceed from there, preferably in a manner less subject to rot if the water problems recur after being fixed. *i.e.* plenty of basements are somewhat damp sometimes, and floors are bare or painted concrete or ceramic tile, so they don't rot even so. But it depends what you are doing with the basement space - and is more of a personal choice/opinion or decorating advice.